# Importing and accessing existing PHP application into XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I am new to PHP (have been a Java guy all my years :-) but understand the basics of it. For an existing application on which I need to fix some bugs, I need to import it into XAMPP.
I tried putting all the application folders (and files) into the htdocs folder of XAMPP. However, that does not work. The server does list the new project when I navigate to **"http://localhost"** but when I click on my project (that I copied), the index.php page fails to come up. It simply says page not found.

I would like to know a couple of things as listed below... 
1) Is there something wrong I am doing for the project to be hosted on XAMPP? 
2) One peculiar thing that I noticed was that when the application browses to http://localhost/MyProject/index.php , it gets redirected to http://www.localhost/index.php . Is there a URLRewriter (or kind) which is doing this? If yes, where I can find the same within my project? 
 
3) How can I identify the framework that the existing code is using? I can see M-V-C named class.php files

Any pointers would be much helpful for me to start debugging and learning PHP.

Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem rather than a code problem

Comment: Yes, seems to me the same too but I don't know where exactly to look being a newbie. Any pointers you have?

Comment: I've never used XAMPP but it is apache. There should be an httpd.conf file somewhere. It probably has configs that are causing you headaches.  As for identifying the framework - Hopefully inside the files there are comments as to what framework they are a part of. If there aren't I'd assume it some kind of custom system.

Comment: I've looked into httpd.conf file, and already modified the <directory >there, into which XAMPP looks for changed files/folders to be deployed.
Interesting point to note is that my other sample apps in the same directory work fine, but not this one. It just redirects to www.localhost/index or types. Some thing in the code base itself, which is redirecting the page.

Comment: Restart Apache after modifications

Comment: @Parkyprg - did that too, and my other sample projects work fine. It's only this new project (already created by someone else) that I am trying to access, which is giving me problem of redirection.

Comment: Maybe is something related to a configuration file of the project - check for a config.php, admin.phpsettings.php and see what is inside.

Comment: I checked the .htaccess file and here is what I found... 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Looks like this is the issue why it is getting redirected?